# Get right column to be next to left column, as opposed to aligned on right

Tags: html, css

How would I get the right div below lined up directly next to the left div? At the moment, the right div seems to be aligned all the way on the right.

**CSS**

```
.leftColumn {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.columnsContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.rightColumn {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1.25em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .leftColumn {
        margin-right: 50%;
    }
    .rightColumn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 35%;
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzf76wgL/1/

Comment: Use one column for all items and `float: left;` on the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it. You can try to use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/yzf76wgL/3/

```
.leftColumn {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    width: 40%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.leftColumn img{
    width:100%;
}
.columnsContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
}
.rightColumn {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1.25em;
    width: 40%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

if you want to change the "size" (width) of the divs, you can change width property of the leftColumn or rightColumn (now they have width:40%;).

Comment: Is it possible to have the images scale to the div as opposed to stretching?

Comment: Image has `width:100%` so it scales with his container. But, if you want a responsive img you should add: `.leftColumn img{width:100%;height:auto;}`

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `.column` and use it on all items, then assign `float: left;` if you want it to be responsive i suggest you use `%` on div with `max-width:` and use CSS media query for different device view and how they align.

http://jsfiddle.net/yzf76wgL/4/